# AdWhirl - Millennial ad return failed. Zero content length returned

Tags: android, adwhirl

i'm trying using MillennialMedia in AdWhirl unsuccessfully due to the "Millennial ad return failed. Zero content length returned" trouble. I couldn't find a solution browsing other posts and mmwebsite.

This is my logcat:

```
09-06 08:53:50.854: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(28584): Showing ad:
09-06 08:53:50.854: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(28584):     nid: ***
09-06 08:53:50.854: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(28584):     name: millennial
09-06 08:53:50.854: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(28584):     type: 6
09-06 08:53:50.854: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(28584):     key: ***
09-06 08:53:50.854: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(28584):     key2: 
09-06 08:53:50.858: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(28584): Valid adapter, calling handle()
09-06 08:53:50.858: DEBUG/MillennialMediaAdSDK(28584): New MMAdView Started
09-06 08:53:50.862: INFO/MillennialMediaAdSDK(28584): Activity: ActivityInfo{47f2a150 com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer}
09-06 08:53:50.862: INFO/MillennialMediaAdSDK(28584): Activity: ActivityInfo{47f24100 com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdViewOverlayActivity}
09-06 08:53:50.975: DEBUG/MillennialMediaAdSDK(28584): callForAd
09-06 08:53:50.987: DEBUG/MillennialMediaAdSDK(28584): Automatic ad fetching is off with -1. You must manually call for ads.
09-06 08:53:50.987: INFO/MillennialMediaAdSDK(28584): No download in progress.
09-06 08:53:50.987: INFO/MillennialMediaAdSDK(28584): Pending download?: false
09-06 08:53:50.987: INFO/MillennialMediaAdSDK(28584): No incomplete downloads.
09-06 08:53:50.987: INFO/MillennialMediaAdSDK(28584): Last ad name is null. Call for new ad.
09-06 08:53:51.018: DEBUG/MillennialMediaAdSDK(28584): Calling for an advertisement: http://androidsdk.ads.mp.mydas.mobi/getAd.php5?***
09-06 08:53:51.018: INFO/MillennialMediaAdSDK(28584): Making ad request
09-06 08:53:51.510: INFO/MillennialMediaAdSDK(28584): Millennial ad return failed. Zero content length returned.
09-06 08:53:51.510: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(28584): Millennial failure
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

this answer might help you:

If I recall correctly, if you just released your app with Millennial, I
think they put your app through a verification period to make sure that the
ad requests are authentic.  From their FAQ:

"I see less fill in your reporting GUI versus my mediation partners, why is
this?
The reporting discrepancy is due to the test campaigns that we initially run
on your inventory when you start up. After the application has launched and
the traffic is verified, we remove these test campaigns in order to ensure
you get live campaigns. Initially you may see discrepancies in reporting,
but this should level out once we have removed the test campaigns from your
application. "
Also, it could just be that they have no ads to serve right now.  Seems like
a lot of ad providers are having fairly low inventory right now.

from: http://groups.google.com/group/adwhirl-users/browse_thread/thread/1e6e6e0826537d1a

Answer (score -1):

I work on Millennial's developer support team and we can definitely help you troubleshoot this.  If you want to shoot us an email with these details, your APID, and the full ad URL that isn't present here, then we'll make sure you get up and running.  Email is developer@millennialmedia.com

Thanks.

Comment: just sent you an email:

<developer@millennialmedia.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in relay recipient table (state 14).

That's so bad..

Comment: Ok.  cbrown@millennialmedia.com is my personal.